# Python line break in long "with x1 as y1, x2 as y2, x3 as y3" statement

Tags: python, syntax

I would like to break a long statement like:

```
with X1() as y1, X2() as y2, X3() as y3:  # Really long line
  # Do something
```

I have tried:

```
with (
    X1() as y1,
    X2() as y2,
    X3() as y3):
  # Do something
```

but this is a syntax error. It seems that the following works, but I find it relatively difficult to read:

```
with X1(
    ) as y1, X2(
    ) as y2, X3(
    ) as y3:
  # Do something
```

Are there any suggestions on how to best format a long `with` statement like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
with X1() as y1, \
    X2() as y2, \
    X3() as y3:
```

Try that. I think it's important to keep the individual statements as one line. The backslash helps keep the explicit > implicit style of Python.

Reference here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/